Touchpad and keyboard freeze for a brief moment - Kubuntu 23.10 - Asus A15 FA507NV
Some months ago I bought a new laptop. The model is Asus A15 FA507NV. When I installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS the keyboard didn't work because the kernel didn't support it. For this reason I installed Kubuntu 23.10 which ships with kernel 6.5.0-27-generic. With this upgrade the keyboard started working.
The issue is that now sometimes the keyboard and mouse stop responding for a few seconds. This happens more frequently when I have the AC adapter plugged in and the PC is charged so continues to switch from charging to using the battery frequently.
I am unable to narrow down what is causing this issue and I believe that there are multiple causes. I suspect that sometimes the whole system becomes unresponsive and other times is just the keyboard or the mouse.
I have tried to disable amd-pstate as suggested here but the behaviour remains the same.
If I run journalctl -xe after the freeze i get different kind of errors and warnings.
The most common are the following:

kernel: rtw89_8852be 0000:04:00.0: firmware failed to ack for entering ps mode This one is solved. See the edit.
amdgpu: SMU: I'm not done with your previous command: SMN_C2PMSG_66:0x00000019 SMN_C2PMSG_82:0x00000000
workqueue: acpi_os_execute_deferred hogged CPU for >10000us 128 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
workqueue: pm_runtime_work hogged CPU for >10000us 16 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND

The error (1.) happens when i disable amd-pstate while (2.,3. and 4.) happen if I leave amd-pstate enabled.
The output of xinput is the following
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUP1205:00 093A:2008 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUP1205:00 093A:2008 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE5570:00 048D:8051                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]

The keyboard should be ITE5570:00 048D:8051 while the touchpad is ASUP1205:00 093A:2008 Touchpad.
Do you have some suggestions on how to narrow down the cause of this issue?
Edit: Error (1.) seems to be related to the bluetooth adapter. I solved this issue by following this thread. The freezes are still happening.
I have asusctl installed
